# How to generate chart of players from database in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, charts

I'm trying to figure out how to generate a competition chart list from users (players) in database.

I'v got a random sorting:

```
def shotokanRandPlayers(request, tournament_id):
  tournament = Tournament.objects.get(id = tournament_id)
  categories = Category.objects.filter(tournament_id = tournament)
  for category in categories:
      if category.type=="KM" and category.playerT_id.all().count()>0:
         playersT = list(category.playerT_id.all())
         random.shuffle(playersT)
         i = 0
         while i<len(playersT):
            first = FirstPlayer.objects.create(player = playersT[i].player_id)
                i=i+1
                if i<len(playersT):
                   second = SecondPlayer.objects.create(player = playersT[i].player_id)
                else:
                   second = None
                Fight.objects.create(category_id = category, firstplayer = first, secondplayer = second, round = 0)
                i=i+1
return redirect('tournament', tournament_id = tournament.id)
```

By now on I would like go generate a ready list of these players to have it looked like this:

[Image](http://media.wonderland.cz/stockphoto/cache/2008/12/14/elimination-pavouk.png)

Are there any django-ready-extensions that would make it ? Or anybody has an idea how to make it ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [graphviz](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/graphviz) ([here](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php) are some examples from its gallery) will let you do something similar to what you want. It is probably only a matter of using the right combination of attributes.

Hope it helps!